# How can I show dynamic options in select, based on another select element using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have two dropdown selects, one for category and one that will list pages.

I want to make the user first select an option from the first (which are parent pages of the other pages), and then for the second dropdown to show only child pages of the select page in the first dropdown.

The way I'm getting th child pages is a PHP function that uses `get_posts` and passes the ID of the parent page selected in the first dropdown.

But I don't know how do run the AJAX call so it calls the function with the selected first value, and then update the second list?

FORM

```
<div id="frontpage-quick-select" class="nav well-bv" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="h2 pull-left">Start your journey</div>
        <form id="bv-quick-select" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="bv-quick-select-category" id="bv-quick-select-category" class="form-control input-lg">
                    <option selected disabled>Choose a body area</option>
                    <?php bv_quick_select_get_category_options(); ?>
                 </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <select name="bv-quick-select-procedure" id="bv-quick-select-procedure" class="form-control input-lg">
                     <option>Choose a procedure</option>

                 </select>
             </div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block-xs">Go</button>
         </form>
     </div>
 </div>
```

FUNCTIONS USED

```
function bv_quick_select_get_category_options() {
    $procedure_pages = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_wp_page_template',
                'value' => 'template-procedure-minimal.php'
            )
        )
    ));
    $procedure_categories = array();
    foreach($procedure_pages as $p1) {
        array_push($procedure_categories, wp_get_post_parent_id($p1->ID));
    }
    sort($procedure_categories);
    $output = '';
    foreach(array_unique($procedure_categories) as $c) {
        $output .= '<option value="'.get_post($c)->post_title.'">'.get_post($c)->post_title.'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}

function bv_quick_select_get_procedure_options($category = null) {
    $procedures = get_posts(array(
        'post_type'  => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => get_page_by_title($category)->ID
    ));
    $output = '';
    foreach($procedures as $p) {
        $output .= '<option value="'.get_the_permalink(get_post($p)->ID).'">'.get_post($p)->post_title.'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

JS used for AJAX

```
$(document).on('change', '#bv-quick-select-category', function() {

    item = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/bv-quick-select-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {value: item},
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });

});
```

My main question is, I know I need to use the function to complete the second dropdown list int he ajax PHP file, but how do I pass through the first ID from the JS file, and how do I then return the contents of the function, back to the JS file and add them to the dropdown?

Comment: change your ajax structure if you are using WordPress then send request according to the WordPress

Comment: The function which through which you want your data back to your JS file just add these two lines after that function `add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );`

Comment: And you also have to give call to wordpress admin-ajax in order to get response back

Comment: Can you explain this in an example? I've tried this, but still can't seem to get the output of the function in the called PHP File, back to the JS file on success (so I can append the target dropdown with the outputs of the PHP function).

Comment: Does the `add_action` go underneath the function in the main plugin php file, or underneath the action inside the AJAX php file?